# Binding a function n times in a monad

Tags: haskell

I have seen the solutions using `iterate` or `replicate` in order to apply a function `n` times.  However, I don't manage to use it inside a State monad.

This code works:

```
-- Stuff an empty game level with obstacles.
generateLevel :: Level -> State StdGen Level
generateLevel lvl =
    placeRandomWall lvl >>= placeRandomWall >>= placeRandomWall
```

This one works as well, unsurprisingly:

```
generateLevel :: Level -> State StdGen Level
generateLevel lvl =
    placeRandomWall =<< placeRandomWall =<< placeRandomWall lvl
```

However, this is not the same as:

```
generateLevel :: Level -> State StdGen Level
generateLevel lvl =
    (placeRandomWall =<< placeRandomWall =<< placeRandomWall) lvl
```

The latest complains about types.  Therefore, I can't `foldl (=<<) id (relicate 42 placeRandomWall)`, nor can I `iterate`.

This makes sense, as iterate take a `a -> a` function, while what I have is `a -> m a` or something like that.  So, I don't really know how to go from there.

Comment: **Hint:** If you have a function `f :: a -> m a`, `(>>= f) :: m a -> m a` which can be iterated.

Comment: This is maybe how they implemented (>=>).  I'll have a look at the code, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for `<=<` and `>=>` from `Control.Monad`.  They can be folded across a list you've made with `replicate` to create one big action.

Try `foldr (<=<) return (replicate 42 placeRandomWall)`.

Comment: Reading about these operators now.  I see you sneakily replaced my foldl by a foldr.  I had a look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27 but it doesn't enlighten me.  Any reason for prefering foldr?

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you.  Kleisli composition makes sense now.

Comment: @Niriel in this particular case, there really isn't a difference between foldl and foldr. But in general, foldr allows more laziness. So I prefer it whenever I don't have a reason to use foldl.

Comment: @Niriel Usually using foldr implies you read your list from the right side (the end of the list) so your accumulator will be constructed by prepending the current item instead of appending it like in foldl.
Prepending (with `:`) is more efficient than appending (with `++`) because you don't have to go through the whole list to put your item at the end of this list.

Comment: @TaurusOlson both `foldl` and `foldr` folds from the left. consider this example: `foldr (&&) True $ repeat False`. how could this ever terminate if foldr started "from the right"? the list is infinite, there is nowhere to start from, but still, it returns `False`. if you do the same thing with `foldl` though, it will loop infinitely.